# Adding groups to Projects in Redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine, member

i'm working on this script -> http://www.redmine.org/plugins/default_members <- by Sajin Andrei

I've completely modified the hook to suite my needs, but i realized that it actually adds every single user that is member of the defined group.

what i want to do is, instead, add the entire group to the project, so that if i add anyone else to the same group i'll not have to update every project.

this is my code:

```
# Debuggin [Default: commented/disabled]
#require 'logger'

class DefmembersHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  def controller_projects_new_after_save(context={ })
    #log = Logger.new('/usr/local/share/redmine/log/plugin.log')
    params = context[:params]
    project = context[:project]
    roles = Role.find_all_givable
    setting_group = Setting.plugin_redmine_default_members[:group] ? Setting.plugin_redmine_default_members[:group] : 'Manager'
    groups ||= setting_group.split(",")
    groups.each do |gp|
      #log.error "gp: #{gp}"
      group = Group.find(:first, :conditions => ["LOWER(lastname) = ?", gp.to_s.downcase])
      #log.error "group: #{group}"
      users = User.active.in_group(group).all(:limit => 100)
      users.each do |user|
        if user[:lastname] != 'Admin' && user[:lastname] != 'Anonymous'
          #log.error "inizio per #{user}"
          rs = Role.find_by_name(group.to_s)
          #log.error "rs: #{rs}"
          m = Member.new(:user => user, :roles => [rs])
          project.members << m
          #log.error "fine per #{user}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and is actually working as intended by Sajin Andrei, adding single users from a group.

i want to do something like this

```
m = Member.new(:group => group, :roles => [rs])
project.members << m
```

but it doesn't work (obviously)...
hope someone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution:

```
# Modificata da CARLO RUGGIERO per RETINA
# Permette di aggiungere interi gruppi ad un progetto in automatico!
class DefmembersHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  def controller_projects_new_after_save(context={ })
    params = context[:params]
    project = context[:project]
    #roles = Role.find_all_givable
    setting_group = Setting.plugin_redmine_default_members[:group] ? Setting.plugin_redmine_default_members[:group] : 'Manager'
    groups ||= setting_group.split(",")
    groups.each do |gp|
      group = Group.find(:first, :conditions => ["LOWER(lastname) = ?", gp.to_s.downcase])
      rs = Role.find_by_name(group.to_s) 
      project.members << Member.new(:principal => group, :roles => [rs])
    end
  end
end
```

the problem was that the **:user** tag only accepts user elements
changing it to **:principal** i've got it to work

```
m = Member.new(:principal => group, :roles => [rs])
project.members << m
```

hope that someone find this usefull